# SSD drive does not boot internally 13" Late 2011 MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I have a late 2011 macbook pro 13" on which i used a kingston 60gb v300 ssd in my primary slot and in the secondary slot i used the 500gb toshiba hdd the macbook pro came with. i've had the ssd since january 2013 and in mid december, it failed. The computer froze all of the sudden, I tried formatting, reinstalling but no luck, the ssd boots fine as an external storage device, but internally it doesn't.

I've sent the ssd to warranty but they said there is no problem with it. right now i'm using the old 500gb 5400rpm drive and it's driving me crazy because it's so slow. I have to mention that the ssd isn't even recognized when i put it in the secondary slot and when i have it in the primary slot and try to go to recovery mode it freezes immediately.

How can I figure out why the SSD doesn't work any more internally?

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: Sorry, my questions is, what is going on with the ssd ? why won't it boot ? when i got it back from warranty they said it was fine and my macbook boots fine with my old 500gb drive and the ssd won't.

Comment: This seems to be extremely similar to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79279/ssd-boot-drive-does-not-work-only-on-primary-drive-slot, how does your situation differ (apart from another SSD type of course)?

Comment: yes, it is similar, but my ssd never booted from caddty

Comment: nevertheless, did you try the solution there?

Comment: i don't know how to insulate the cable and i can't get a new flex cable in my country without paying a ridiculous price...

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so soon after this happened the 500GB 5400 rpm HDD failed also. I took it to Apple and the drive connector/cable was damaged from overheating they said. They changed the cable and it works great now.